# Get Post Type with Parents, Children AND Meta Data

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display **on the home-page of my site** all posts under a custom post type. This in itself is easy to do, but I can't find a way to structure it correctly. I want to display the info in this manner:

```
    Parent Page
     - Child Page
    [Meta data from above child]
    - Child Page
    [Meta data from above child]
```

The following is CLOSE to what I need, but it simply spits out all pages, parents and children. I need them grouped under what they belong to:

```
<?php
$arr_query_args = array(
    'numberposts'  => -1,
    'post_type'    => 'tours',
    'orderby'   => 'title', 
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$arr_posts = get_posts( $arr_query_args );

global $post;

foreach( $arr_posts as $this_post ) { ?>

    <?php $museum = get_post_meta( $this_post->ID, 'tour_museum', true ); // The museum ?>
    <?php $permalink = get_permalink($this_post->ID); // Get the post's permalink ?>
    <?php $parent_title = get_the_title($this_post->post_parent); // Post parent title ?>
    <?php $parentId = $this_post->post_parent; $linkToParent = get_permalink($parentId); // Post parent URL ?>

    <li class="<?php echo $parent_title; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $linkToParent; ?>"><?php echo $parent_title; ?></a>
    <ul class="children">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php echo $this_post->post_title ?></a></li>
    </ul>
    <small><?php echo $museum; ?></small>
    </li>

<?php } ?>
```

I've looked all over and have tested several things, but cannot get the structure right. I don't need the content of parent or child pages, just titles, permalink and some meta data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are fetching the posts, it will fetch ALL posts regardless of who the parent is, so, in order to achieve the hierarchical display, the solutions that you can use:

1. Fetch Top level parents by setting `post_parent => 0` in `WP_Query` function

e.g.

```
$arr_query_args = array(
    'numberposts'  => -1,
    'post_type'    => 'tours',
    'orderby'   => 'title', 
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'post_parent'  => 0
);

$parent_posts = get_posts( $arr_query_args );
```

2. Then loop over Top level parents and use those parents' IDs to fetch their child by setting `post_parent => $parent->ID` in `WP_Query` function

e.g.

```
while($parent_posts->have_posts()): $parent_posts->the_post();

    $arr_query_args_child = array(
        'numberposts'  => -1,
        'post_type'    => 'tours',
        'orderby'   => 'title', 
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'post_parent'  => get_the_ID()
    );

    $child_posts = get_posts( $arr_query_args_child );

    // loop for child post here and fetch meta data etc.

endwhile;
```

3. Then use Child's ID the fetch relevant metadata using `get_post_meta` function.

Using the above approach, you should be able to achieve your desired output.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So having done this, the first part of my query now reads:

`$arr_query_args = array(
    'numberposts'  => -1,
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'post_parent' => $parent->ID,
    'post_type'    => 'tours',
    'orderby'  => 'title', 
 'order'  => 'ASC',
);`

But of course that doesn't change anything, what I need to do, but am not sure HOW to do, is to use these changes to get the child pages. How do I echo out the children in (what I would consider) the body of my code using `$parent->$ID`?

Comment: I can’t close this as I’ve not yet been given enough details to resolve my issue ;_;

Comment: @Toasterdroid, i have edited my answer and have added more details, refer to the answer, it should be clear now.